# Access Violation With Freetype and OpenGL

Tags: c++, freetype

When I run my program, the window displays for about 3 seconds (with a white background as expected, but no text) and then breaks, saying there was an access violation in the FreeType code. I'm pretty sure this is with loading the font, because my debug text prints that it couldn't find it, and it also can't use the width and height of the face, so it returns an error. I've tried putting arial.ttf in the .exe directory, project directory, everywhere. No dice. Here's my main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
        int running = GL_TRUE;

        debug.Print("Program initialized...");
        window.Create( 800, 600, "OpenGL");

        TEXT text;

        while( running )
        {
                glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
                glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

                glEnable(GL_BLEND);
                glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

                text.Create("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "arial.ttf", 300, 400, 1, 1, 1,   2/600, 2/800);

                glfwSwapBuffers();
        }

        glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);

        glDeleteProgram( shaderProgram );
        glDeleteShader( fragmentShader );
        glDeleteShader( vertexShader );

        glDeleteBuffers( 1, &vbo );

        debug.Print("Program terminated.");
}
```

Here's my Text.h:

```
#ifndef _TEXT
#define _TEXT

#include "debug.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

class TEXT
{
public:
        void Create(char* Text, char* fontName, int posx, int posy, int r, int g, int b, int sizex, int sizey);
};

#endif
```

Here's my Text.cpp:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "text.h"

const char* textvertexSource =
        "version 150\n"
        "in vec4 coord;"
        "out vec2 texcoord;"
        "void main {"
        "       gl_Position = vec4(coord.xy, 0, 1);"
        "       texcoord = coord.zw;"
        "}";

const char* textfragmentSource =
        "version  150\n"
        "in vec2 texcoord;"
        "uniform sampler2D tex;"
        "uniform vec4 color;"
        "void main() {"
        "       gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, texture2D(tex, texcoord).a * color;"
        "}";

void TEXT::Create(char* text, char* fontName, int posx, int posy, int r, int g, int b, int sizex, int sizey)
{

        // OpenGL functions
        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
        glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &textvertexSource, NULL );
        glCompileShader( vertexShader );

        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
        glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &textfragmentSource, NULL );
        glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

        GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
        glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
        glBindFragDataLocation( shaderProgram, 0, "outColor" );
        glLinkProgram( shaderProgram );
        glUseProgram( shaderProgram );

        GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "coord" );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "color" );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        GLint uniform_tex = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex");

        GLuint tex;
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glGenTextures(1, &tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        glUniform1i(uniform_tex, 0);

        GLuint uniform_color = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        // Actual font rendering
        FT_Library ft;

        if(FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
                debug.Print("Could not initiate freetype library.");

        FT_Face face;
        if(FT_New_Face(ft, fontName, 0, &face))
        {
                debug.Print("Could not load font: ");
                debug.Print(fontName);
        }

        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, sizex, sizey);

        FT_GlyphSlot glyph = face->glyph;

        const char *p;

        for(p = text; *p; p++) {
                if(FT_Load_Char(face, *p, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
                        continue;

                glTexImage2D(
                  GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                  0,
                  GL_ALPHA,
                  glyph->bitmap.width,
                  glyph->bitmap.rows,
                  0,
                  GL_ALPHA,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  glyph->bitmap.buffer
                );

                float x2 = posx + glyph->bitmap_left * sizex;
                float y2 = -posy - glyph->bitmap_top * sizey;
                float w = glyph->bitmap.width * sizex;
                float h = glyph->bitmap.rows * sizey;

                GLfloat box[4][4] = {
                        {x2,     -y2    , 0, 0},
                        {x2 + w, -y2    , 1, 0},
                        {x2,     -y2 - h, 0, 1},
                        {x2 + w, -y2 - h, 1, 1},
                };

                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof box, box, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

                posx += (glyph->advance.x >> 6) * sizex;
                posy += (glyph->advance.y >> 6) * sizey;

                GLfloat color[4] = {r, g, b, 1};
                glUniform4fv(uniform_color, 1, color);
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to break create in two, a creation phase and a rendering phase... every loop you reinitialize FreeType and recreate everything!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to expand on my comment.

In your `while( running )` loop, you call `text.Create("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "arial.ttf", 300, 400, 1, 1, 1,   2/600, 2/800);`. When looking at the specifics of this function, it does way more than simply create a new text entry, it initializes `FreeType`, loads `fonts`, etc...

You want your game/simulation to initialize `FreeType` only once and have `text.Create` return an object that will last throughout your game/simulation.

In the `while(running)` part, you should call a `Render` method on the object to have it rendered on the screen.

Comment: Ok, no more errors, but now the text just isn't rendering. Here's my revised code:

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are setting FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes with sizex and sizey and then when creating the box for the text you use sizex and sizey to scale the box.

So if you set sizex and sizey to 48 that also means your scaling your text box by 48 which is way to big, and if you set sizex and sizey to 1 then the pixel size of your font is super small.

**To fix: add parameter- size or height and width to create function and use it for FT_Set_Pixel_Size**

ex.

```
void Create(char* Text, char* fontName, int posx, int posy, int r, int g, int b, int sizex, int sizey, int height, int width){
...
FT_Set_Pixel_Size(face, width, height); //Not sizex and sizey because thats what you are using to scale the text box
}
```